# Integrate tooltips with CHM help in Windows app

Tags: delphi, tooltip, chm

We're trying to redesign our documentation process for a Windows desktop application, and two of the requirements we have are

- Provide 'reference' help in a CHM format
- Provide tooltip help on individual controls

Currently our tooltips are hard-coded into the Delphi/C++Builder forms, but I'd ideally like to avoid the duplication, and have the CHM file as the 'master'

How can we display the Help information in the CHM file as tooltips when the user positions the mouse over certain controls?

Comment: You can call `HtmlHelp` passing `HH_DISPLAY_TEXT_POPUP`. Details here: http://helpware.net/htmlhelp/how_to_whatsthis.htm

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Won't that bring up a popup that has to be explicitly closed by the user? Is there a way extracting the text that would be displayed, and setting the control's Hint property?

Comment: No, that will bring up a hint window. I don't know how to extract text. It's probably possible. It may be easier to do what I suggest above.

Comment: Davids link is dead now, use the time machine to view it: http://web.archive.org/web/20090410044115/http://www.helpware.net/htmlhelp/how_to_whatsthis.htm

Comment: The `What's this` information was moved to:
http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/whatsthis